# Return duplicate count for records

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i go about adding in a count to show the number of duplicates that are found based on the rules i have in the sql? I am trying to find duplicate records where they have duplicates for only country of inc and company reg number. So i only want to find duplicates where the gtid is unique to each duplicate, and the country of incorporation along with company reg number have a count > 1

```
  select distinct top 10000 wp1.GtId, 
  wp1.CrmPartyId, 
  wp1.LegalName, 
  wp1.BusinessClass, 
  wp1.RmFullName, 
  wp1.PbeFullName, 
  wp1.OverallClientStatus, 
  wp1.OverallRpStatus, 
  wp1.FirstName,
  wp1.LastName,  
 wp1.CompanyRegNum,
   wp1.CountryInc,
  wp2.GtId, 
  wp2.CrmPartyId, 
  wp2.LegalName, 
  wp2.BusinessClass, 
  wp2.RmFullName, 
  wp2.PbeFullName, 
  wp2.OverallClientStatus, 
  wp2.OverallRpStatus,  
  wp2.FirstName,
  wp2.LastName,
     wp2.CompanyRegNum,
     wp2.CountryInc
  from CORE.WeccoParty wp1
  join CORE.WeccoParty wp2 on   wp1.CompanyRegNum = wp2.CompanyRegNum
                     and  wp1.CountryInc  = wp2.CountryInc
                     and  wp1.GtId     <> wp2.GtId

  where wp1.CompanyRegNum is not null
  and wp1.OverallClientStatus = 'Onboarded' and wp2.OverallClientStatus = 
 'Onboarded'
  and wp1.OverallRpStatus = 'Onboarded' and wp2.OverallRpStatus = 
  'Onboarded'
  and lower(WP1.CompanyRegNum) NOT IN     
  ('0','.','n.a','n/a','n.a.','00000','unknown','Unknown','000000','00000000')
  and wp1.CompanyRegNum NOT LIKE('^0*0$')
  and   wp1.CountryInc is not null
```

Comment: Use `row_number`

Comment: You have a couple logical issues going on here. First you say you want to find duplicates, but you have distinct in your query. Second you have top but you have no order by. This means you can't ensure which rows are returned.

Comment: hi, i have edited the question. Hopefully it is more clear what results i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please do not code dump the whole query into the question. Please edit it down to the minimum possible that shows the problem. For example, you can remove nearly all of the selected columns without affecting the question. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

use the window function `OVER()` and your rule for duplicate in `PARTITION BY`

```
duplicate_count = count(*) OVER ( wp2.CompanyRegNum, wp2.CountryInc )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RANK [Rank Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or Count

Below are two example how to get what you are after if I understand you correctly. It's good for finding what combinations/duplications that exist in your table.

Using RANK:
If rn>1 it means that there are several occurences of the combination (with different GtId).

You can put this in your query and if you make your query an inner query you can simply select all rows with rn >1 to find the the combinations you are looking for. **But please remember** that a row can still have rn=1 even though it exist duplicates for that combination.

```
RANK() OVER(Partition by wp1.CountryInc,wp2.CompanyRegNum ORDER BY wp2.GtId desc ) as rn
```

Like this

```
select * from 
    (Select wp1.CountryInc,wp2.CompanyRegNum,wp2.GtId,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by wp1.CountryInc,wp2.CompanyRegNum OVER wp2.GtId ) as rn
  from CORE.WeccoParty wp1
  join CORE.WeccoParty wp2 on   wp1.CompanyRegNum = wp2.CompanyRegNum
                     and  wp1.CountryInc  = wp2.CountryInc
                     and  wp1.GtId     <> wp2.GtId

  where wp1.CompanyRegNum is not null
  and wp1.OverallClientStatus = 'Onboarded' and wp2.OverallClientStatus = 
 'Onboarded'
  and wp1.OverallRpStatus = 'Onboarded' and wp2.OverallRpStatus = 
  'Onboarded'
  and lower(WP1.CompanyRegNum) NOT IN     
  ('0','.','n.a','n/a','n.a.','00000','unknown','Unknown','000000','00000000')
  and wp1.CompanyRegNum NOT LIKE('^0*0$')
  and   wp1.CountryInc is not null )q
  where q.rn >1
```

Using Count:

```
 Select wp1.CountryInc,wp2.CompanyRegNum, COUNT(Distinct wp2.GtId) as NoOfDuplicates
 from CORE.WeccoParty wp1
  join CORE.WeccoParty wp2 on   wp1.CompanyRegNum = wp2.CompanyRegNum
                     and  wp1.CountryInc  = wp2.CountryInc
                     and  wp1.GtId     <> wp2.GtId

  where wp1.CompanyRegNum is not null
  and wp1.OverallClientStatus = 'Onboarded' and wp2.OverallClientStatus = 
 'Onboarded'
  and wp1.OverallRpStatus = 'Onboarded' and wp2.OverallRpStatus = 
  'Onboarded'
  and lower(WP1.CompanyRegNum) NOT IN     
  ('0','.','n.a','n/a','n.a.','00000','unknown','Unknown','000000','00000000')
  and wp1.CompanyRegNum NOT LIKE('^0*0$')
  and   wp1.CountryInc is not null 
  group by wp1.CountryInc,wp2.CompanyRegNum
  having COUNT(Distinct wp2.GtId)  >1
```

Comment: where abouts in the query do i insert this?

Comment: Anywhere you like in the select clause

Comment: thanks for this. So as you mentioned. this will give me the records who have a unique gtid, but have duplicates for country inc + country reg? The rn will show the count of each one

Comment: Yes, but please bear in mind that the first row will have rn=1 and second, third duplicate will have have 2,3.. etc.
please try it and make sure it works as you expect. And if it does please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: When i run my SQL at the very top. I get over 16 records with a country of inc from UK. When i run your sql using the COUNT as you have above, i 8 records with duplicates saying it is from UK. I do not understand

Comment: It might have to do with what I mentioned in the previous comment. If you select the distinct CountryInc,CompanyRegNum instead of select * from the first query you'll probably get 8 rows. It has to do with that in the second query you get distinct wp1.CountryInc,wp2.CompanyRegNum but in the first query you get one row for each duplicate (exept the first duplicate with rn =1)